# Ivri and Israeli

Tags: words, parashas-emor

In many parts of the torah,  When it talks about a jew it says,  בני ישראל or עברי etc. However in Parashat Emor when talking about the son of Shlomit the daughter of divri from the tribe of Dan who cursed Hashem's name,  it says ישראלית.  What is the difference?

Comment: I believe that this is **mainly** historical. Avraham was the first person in Tanac"h to be called an *Ivri*. Obviously, since Jacob hadn't been born, he couldn't be called *Yisraeli*. When relaying to Pharaoh, Moses says "The G-d of the *Ivrim*", so there's another reference. Ivri isn't used that often. The only other place I can think of is that Jonah also calls himself an *Ivri*, but I have to investigate why.

Comment: @DanF Yonah probably used the word Ivri to make the distinction that he was from the Kingdom of Judah, and not from the Kingdom of Israel. But since he wasn't from the Tribe of Judah he didn't use "Yehudi". (The commentators say he was either from Asher or Zebulun.)

Comment: @ezra Your reasoning **might** be faulty. Compare the reference to Mordechai who is called **both** a *Yehudi* and *Yemini*. Despite the fact that he was from tribe of Benjamin, he was still called a *Yehudi*. The question is at what point, historically did **all** Jews become called *Yehudim*? Offhand, I think Jonah precedes this change, but, I'm mentioning the possibility that the term *Yehudi* might have been used at Jonah's time as well as a generic term, despite that Jonah didn't use it. Certainly, all people would be called *Ivrim*.

Comment: @DanF Except that there is a special connection between Benjamin and Judah, because Judah promised Benjamin's safety on his life.

Comment: @ezra Yes, I hear you about both that as well as the notion that Bet Hamikdash was partially in Yehuda, partially in Binyamin. But, I don't know if those criteria explain the usage of the terms and why Mordechai was referred to as both.

Comment: Actually, after the Exodus, the term "Ivri" is only used in one of two ways: 1. When referring to Israelites slaves. 2. When non-Israelites talk about Israelites. The one exception, if I'm not mistaken, is Yonah when talking to the sailors, and per what we know about the usage of the term, it seems to make sense - he explains to them who he is per how non-Israelites would have referred to him (the sailors weren't Israelites).